# Comparing Two arrays of objects to obtain different results

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
 accounts: [ 
  { 
    uuid: '47833371-753a-412a-a00c-b43fc48b662b',
    cash: 50000 
  }, { 
    uuid: 'b9a30e79-7dc6-45c7-b277-6f03b43f0f9a',
    cash: 40000 
  } 
],
participations: [ 
  { 
    product_id: '0ebe9585-9506-4e28-8ca1-561726d51e30',
    number_participations: 283,
    net_asset_value: '4.0000000000',
    id_account: '47833371-753a-412a-a00c-b43fc48b662b' 
  },{ 
    product_id: '658d56f9-37f6-44ea-b528-861068be4743',
    number_participations: 100,
    net_asset_value: '8.0000000000',
    id_account: '47833371-753a-412a-a00c-b43fc48b662b' 
  } 
] 
}
```

I have two arrays of objects, I want to go through both at the same time, and obtain the patrimony of each of them separately, and then, when listing all accounts, each one has its patrimony added to its object.

```
let patrimony = 0
for (let i = 0; i < participations.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < accounts.length; j++) {
        if (participations[i].uuid_account === accounts[j].uuid) {
            patrimony += participations[i].participations * parseFloat(participations[i].net_asset_value);
        }
    }
}
```

With my approach, what I am getting is simply the sum of the participations multiply for the asset value of the participation of both accounts.

```
"accounts": [
  {
    "uuid": "47833371-753a-412a-a00c-b43fc48b662b",
    "patrimony": 1932,

  },
  {
    "uuid": "b9a30e79-7dc6-45c7-b277-6f03b43f0f9a",
    "patrimony": 1932,
  }
]
```

What I want and I don't know how it's to get the patrimony of each account and add it to correspondent object. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The looped variables don't seem to match the data structure you have provided.

Comment: I think is right, but with the code I posted, it's understandable, right?

Comment: If I understand correctly what's going on, it looks like you are only setting patrimony to 0 outside the loops, when in fact you want to set it to 0 at the beginning of each iteration of the top level loop. So steps to fix would be: set patrimony to 0 at the beginning of loop 1, attach patrimony to accounts object at the end of loop 1 (after loop 2 is done).

Comment: Well, I don't see where you have defined `participations[i].uuid_account` nor `participations[i].participations`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a few errors. 
Please check the fix here.

```html
   let patrimony = 0
for (let i = 0; i < participations.length; i++) {


    for (let j = 0; j < accounts.length; j++) {
       // error if (participations[i].uuid_account === accounts[j].uuid) {
        if (participations[i].id_account === accounts[j].uuid) {
            // error patrimony += participations[i].participations * parseFloat(participations[i].net_asset_value);
            patrimony += participations[i].number_participations * parseFloat(participations[i].net_asset_value);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The description of the problem doesn't exactly match the provided code, but I guess you could use a combination of `map / filter / reduce` to get your results. This is how I would do it, assuming `accounts` and `participants` are object keys of a `data` object:

```
data.accounts = data.accounts.map(function (account) {
  account.patrimony = data.participations
    .filter(function (participation) {
      return participation.id_account === account.uuid;
    })
    .reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {
      return accumulator + (currentValue.number_participations * parseFloat(currentValue.net_asset_value));
    }, 0);

  return account;
});
```

Here's a link showing the full working code:

https://jsfiddle.net/fv7hb8oL/

Comment: with that I get undefined in patrimony, so I don't think is the solution

Comment: @JS4 I had an error in the reduce function. I updated my answer and this code should be working. I tested it.